# Angular 8 Upload image to ApiController c# stop working after upgrade from Angular 7

Tags: c#, .net, angular, angular8

I am using Angular 8.I sending image to my  ApiController to save the image.
I have used before Angular 7 all was working,after upgrade to Angular 8 i dont receive the file.

I see the name and the length of the file in the console when i sendit,but i dont see it in Api.

What i am missing here?

My Angular ts

```
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { UserClaims } from './../../authentication/models/user-claims.model';
import { PrivateZoneLoginService } from './../private-zone-login.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatBottomSheetRef } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'src/app/app-services/local-storage.service';
import { PrivateZoneConstants } from '../private-zone-constans';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bottom-sheet',
  templateUrl: './bottom-sheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bottom-sheet.component.css']
})
export class BottomSheetComponent implements OnInit {

  token = this.pzLogin.userLoginAccessToken;
  public imagePath;
  imgURL: any = this.pzLogin.UserLoginClaims.ImageUrl;
  public message: string;
  fileData = new FileReader();
  reader = new FileReader();
  fileUploaded: boolean = false; 
  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _bottomSheetRef: MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetComponent>,
    private http: HttpClient, private pzLogin: PrivateZoneLoginService,
    private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

  openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
    this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }


  preview(event) {

    if (event.files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const mimeType = event.files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      this.message = 'Only images are supported.';
      return;
    }

    const fileSize = event.files[0].size;
    if (fileSize > 500839) {
      this.message = 'Maximum upload file size 200 kb.';
      return;
    }

     this.reader.readAsDataURL(event.files[0]);

     this.reader.onload = () => {
     this.imgURL = this.reader.result;
     this.fileData = event.files;
     this._bottomSheetRef.containerInstance.enter();
    };

  }

  onSubmit() {

    this.loading = true;
   const formData = new FormData();


    formData.append('UploadedFile', this.fileData[0], this.fileData[0].name);
    formData.append('token',this.token);
    this.http.post(PrivateZoneConstants.UploadUserImage, formData)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.localStorageService.setItem('UserLoginClaims', res);
        this.fileUploaded = true;
        this.loading = false;
        this._bottomSheetRef.containerInstance.enter();
      });

     setTimeout(() => {
        this._bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
      }, 6000);
    }
}
```

My Api

```
[HttpPost]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult UploadUserImage()
{


    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    int i = httpRequest.Files.Count; // here count is 0
    HttpPostedFile postedFileTest = httpRequest.Files[0];


  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add headers by your self.

**And check that your HttpInterceptor does not overwriting  your headers**

This will fix the problem

```
const HttpUploadOptions = new HttpHeaders();
HttpUploadOptions.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
HttpUploadOptions.append('Accept', 'image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg');

this.http.post(PrivateZoneConstants.UploadUserImage, formData, 
  {
  headers: HttpUploadOptions,
  reportProgress: true
}).subscribe(res => {
    this.localStorageService.setItem('UserLoginClaims', res);
    this.fileUploaded = true;
    this.loading = false;
    this._bottomSheetRef.containerInstance.enter();
  });
```